# How to best apply Spring, Spring MVC and Hibernate frameworks

Tags: spring, gwt, frameworks, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm an individual programmer, developer and I see a huge demand for the frameworks: Spring, Spring MVC, webflow, and Hibernate.  Popular today: Spring MVC, webflow, GWT.

I've been going through the tutorials, and the technology looks awesome !
What I would like to know, is.. It's used in corporate sites, why not for smaller sites.   How can I apply these frameworks in building websites ?

I can't imaging doing any kind of serious website building without a modern CMS or Portal framework (whether in Java/php-opensource),  And yes, MVC gives you the validation and authentication hooks to be used.

All the demo's on Spring, cover some elementary, contrived example.
If I learn these technologies (and I'm well on my way), how do I put them into practice, and in what context (no pun intented) do I use them ? 
I don't want to rebuild a CMS system, but I'd like to employ these frameworks effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Magnolia/Blossom](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/modules/blossom.html).
Magnolia is a Java (JCR) based Repository, and Blossom some kind of Spring integration.

I used it in one of my project, it worked. (Not all Spring 3.0 Features worked - for example I was not able to map two or more urls to one controller), but it worked) And I was not able to find any other mature Spring based CMS.

**At least I belive the power of Spring MVC is more in web based applications than in simple web sites.**

Comment: Agreed, I found some pretty cool stuff, when I googled: JCR Implementation like: 15 useful java based CMS http://blog.dreamcss.com/content-management-system/java-based-cms/ and various other platforms JackRabbit, Sencha, Walrus and others.  Of course the forums at  springsource.org are awfully good !